# How to connect to WSL Docker Container using localhost keyword

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, ms-sql, docker-compose

Is there some way to connect to a container, running inside WSL 2, using the keyword localhost instead of 127.0.0.1:port?

To give more context, I have a Docker Compose to run a Microsoft SQL Server instance configured like this:

```
services:
  sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    user: root
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "redacted"
    volumes:
      - sql-server-volume:/var/opt/mssql/data

volumes:
  sql-server-volume:
```

It is very simple and works like a charm except that I need to connect via 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. It is like this for application, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and others.

Is there some way to access containers running inside WSL using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1?

Comment: That's an IPv6 vs IPv4 problem. Or an IPv4 fallback problem, depending how you look at it. (You'd better get used to it, this fallback mechanism is slowly going to disappear.)

Comment: Why do you need to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Using localhost is far easier because it is the default on a lot of projects I work. For example in connection strings. Otherwise I would need to change connection strings everytime to run an application locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution!

I had to disable IPV6 on the WSL network adapter. That solved my routing problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use "localhost" to connect, or even just a dot "." since the port 1433 is being mapped locally to your host computer, and since the port 1433 is the default port for SQL Server. Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: Unfortunately just doesn't work. Same behavior as when a host can't be resolved.

TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to localhost.

------------------------------

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)